# Dynamic php pages based on user role

Tags: php, mysql

I have hit a cross roads with my database design and believe it to be flawed but hoping somebody could assist because I am so far into the build.

Tables:

```
**users**
user_id  | user_email      | user_role | dashboard_id
1        | admin@admin.com | 0         | 1
2        | user@user.com   | 1         | 2
---------------------------------------------------

**dashboards**
dashboard_id | dashboard_name | 
1            | dashboard 1
2            | dashboard 2
---------------------------------------------------

**roles**
role_id | role_name | 
0       | super_admin
1       | user
---------------------------------------------------
```

Superadmins: they login and they go to a top level page where they can create a new dashboard.

User: can login and taken to the dashboard they are associated to.

Superadmins: to have the ability to click on the dashboards and view that dashboard, but as you can see they are also bound to dashboard.

Now, I display the information on the dashboard by getting the users ID in the session and also getting the value from the dashboard_id form the users table and the match them like so:

```
function clientReportName() {
global $conn;
global $dashboardIdNew;
global $user_dash_id;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM dashboards WHERE dashboard_id = $user_dash_id";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            echo $row["dashboard_name"];        
        }
    }
}
```

What the above does is gives me the title of the dashboard they are associated to.

the issue I have is HOW to retain the top level dashboard and allow super admins the view any dashboard and keep the users to only see/access the dashboards they are associated too.

Comment: Could you not associate super admins to dashboards? Just have it so any super admin can look at any dashboard?

Comment: Hey @JordanS thats exactly what im after but im not sure how to from this point

Comment: You just need to retrieve the user row from the session user_id. If it is a superadmin, you display some additional code - such as all the dashboards. I.e. you run another query selecting *all* the dashboards.

Comment: @LSerni I kinda thought that would be the case but i'm so stumped I don't even know where to start! It's one of those thats I have been looking at it too long

Comment: I have a feeling that you need to look back at your design - and maybe visit http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a check to the beginning of your function that checks if a `GET` parameter is set for `dashboard_id`.

If it is, check the user is a `super_admin` and that the requested dashboard exists.

If that's also true, then set `$user_dash_id` to the value of the requested id instead of getting it from the DB

You will obviously need to add links so the admins can pick from a list or something and select their preferred dashboard.

Example:

```
<?php
function clientReportName()
{
    global $conn;
    global $user_id; //you'll need to provide the user_id
    global $user_dash_id;

    if(isset($_GET['dashboard_id']) && is_numeric($_GET['dashboard_id'])){

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = $user_id AND `user_role` = 0";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if($result->num_rows > 0){
            //they are super_admin

            $dash_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['dashboard_id']); //this is probably inadequate to protect you from SQL injection

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `dashboards` WHERE `dashboard_id` = $dash_id";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);

            if($result->num_rows > 0){
                //The requested dashboard exists, so set it as the new id to be requested
                $user_dash_id = $dash_id;
            }
        }
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM dashboards WHERE dashboard_id = $user_dash_id";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo $row["dashboard_name"];
        }
    }
}
```

This may need some refactoring, but I think it shows the idea.

Comment: Im not really sure what you mean sorry, I have tried to follow... what im essentially trying to do is let an admin view any dashboard regardless but only users can view dashboard they are bound too

Comment: Hey I have implemented the code it all makes sense to me but still it does not as the 'super_admin' show me the dashboard based on the GET param

Comment: Ok I am a little closer, if I var_dump on $user_id I get NULL, I set the variable on the page before from my session